# Erro ao criar Virtualenv no Windows

Tags: python, virtualenv

Estou tentando criar um virtualenv no windows mas estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

```
line = line.decode(fs_encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 283: invalid continuation byte
```

Estou usando a versão 3.8 do python. Criei uma pasta chamada virtualenv para ficar os meus projetos.

Pelo PowerShell estou usando o seguinte comando: `virtualenv vir --no-site-packages`

Por ser uma máquina do local em que trabalho, ela faz o uso de proxy, mas não creio que seja isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tava tendo esse mesmo problema, renomeei o arquivo  `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` e rodei o `powershell` como administrador e funcionou, mas ainda não sei ao certo o que causou e o que solucionou a falha...

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi. Você renomeou qual arquivo e para qual nome?